# Loop function parameters for sanity check

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, sanitization

I have a Python function in which I am doing some sanitisation of the input parameters:

```
def func(param1, param2, param3):
    param1 = param1 or ''
    param2 = param2 or ''
    param3 = param3 or ''
```

This caters for the arguments being passed as *None* rather than empty strings. Is there an easier/more concise way to loop round the function parameters to apply such an expression to all of them. My actual function has nine parameters.

Comment: Given how complex the working answers look right now, I think a good question to ask is why does it matter? What are you calling in your function that cares about the difference between None and '' ?

Comment: Hmm, I wrote that a while ago (and was trying to tidy it up today). Maybe I need to revisit why I thought it was necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a good job for a decorator. How about this:

```
def sanitized(func):
    def sfunc(*args, **kwds):
        return func(*[arg or '' for arg in args],
                    **dict((k, v or '') for k,v in kwds.iteritems()))
    sfunc.func_name = func.func_name
    sfunc.func_doc = func.func_doc
    return sfunc
```

You would use this on your function like so:

```
@sanitized
def func(param1, param2, param3):
    print param1, param2, param3
```

Then the parameters will be replaced by the empty string if they are false:

```
>>> func('foo', None, 'spam')
foo  spam
```

(Note that this will still mess up the function signature as Ned Batchelder points out in his answer. To fix that you could use [Michele Simionato's decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator)-- I think you'd just need to add a `@decorator` before the definition of `sanitized`)

Comment: I think you also need to pass along the kwargs too:  

**dict((k, arg or '') for k, arg in kwargs.items()))

Comment: Yes, this is by far the best solution (other than refactoring the original code to not require it.)

Comment: you should probably change the `arg or ''` to `'' if arg is None else arg` or something similar just in case arg is 0 or {} or something non-None.

Answer (score 2):

You could do some list manipulation:

```
def func(param1, param2, param3):
    param1, param2, param3 = map(lambda x: x or '', (param1, param2, param3))
```

but I'm not sure that's better than just writing out the nine lines, since once you get to nine parameters, that's a heinously long line.

You could change the declaration of the function:

```
def func(*args):
    param1, param2, param3 = map(lambda x: x or '', args)
```

but then you lose the documentation that comes from having real parameter names, as well as the possibility of changing the defaults, etc.  And you still have a pretty fugly line there to unpack them.

I say write out the nine lines, or change the function to have fewer parameters: nine is kind of a lot anyway!

Answer (score -2):

```
def func(x='', y='', z='hooray!'):
    print x, y, z

In [2]: f('test')
test  hooray!

In [3]: f('test', 'and')
test and hooray!

In [4]: f('test', 'and', 'done!')
test and done!
```